# Modify PHP to Stop Ads from Appearing after the First Paragraph

Tags: php, ads

This code displays Ads after every 5 paragraphs but it starts after the first paragraph. How can I make it start displaying Ads after the first 5 paragraphs?

```
//Insert ads after every 5th paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
    $ad_code = '<center>AD CODE</center>';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 5, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

// Parent Function
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $index % $paragraph_id === 0 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function beneath. I added a new variable $contentWithAds which
gets its content in a for loop.

You have to replace "your-ads" with the ads you want to insert
and "your-content" with your content.

The answer is complete. You don't need extra code.

```
<?php
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) 
{
$contentWithAds = "";
$closing_p = '</p>';
$paragraphs = explode($closing_p, $content);

for($x=0; $x<count($paragraphs); $x++)
{
    $y = $x + 1;
    if($y % $paragraph_id === 0)
    {
    $contentWithAds .= $paragraphs[$x].$closing_p.$insertion;
    }
    else
    {
    $contentWithAds .= $paragraphs[$x].$closing_p;
    }
}
return $contentWithAds;
}

$paragraph_id = 5;
$insertion = "your-ads";
$content = "your-content";

print prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content );
?>
```

Comment: It's not working. The page content suddenly disappears

Comment: I added the definitions and the call of your parent function. Now the answer is complete.